# Code doesn't work, button isn't responding

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have created register activity which sends data to database, and the button has to open another activity, which is MainActivity. The code works fine, but theres one problem. When the button is being clicked, it responds and sends the information to database, but the activity isn't changing.

How could I change the code to open another activity?

RegisterRequest.java

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://loginacti.comli.com/Register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String Expect, String Prize, String Name, String Email, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("Expect", Expect);
    params.put("Prize", Prize);
    params.put("Name", Name);
    params.put("Email", Email);

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

RegisterActivity.java

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etUknown = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUknown);
    final EditText etPrize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPrize);
    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String Expect = etUknown.getText().toString();
            final String Prize = etPrize.getText().toString();
            final String Name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String Email = etEmail.getText().toString();


            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };


            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(Expect, Prize, Name, Email, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eRegister);

    registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

activity_register.xml

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etUknown"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Numbers" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etPrize"
    android:hint="Secret CD"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUknown"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etUknown"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etUknown" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:hint="Full Name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPrize"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etPrize"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etPrize"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
    android:hint="New Email"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etName" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/bRegister"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etEmail"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Look at his code. The RegisterActivity is in the manifest

Comment: Do you have any errors in logcat after pressing button?

Comment: I have RegisterActivity on the manifest. No, because I tried on real device

Comment: I will check logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add one more Permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: This had really helped to me!

Answer (score 2):

In a onclick you cant use .finish() which would normally exit the current activity. You can however make a method exitActivity() and then call it from your onclick. So in the end of your onClick after you have written to your database make a try block with:

```
try {
     exitActivity();
}
catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And then in your RegisterActivity make a exitActivity() like this:

```
private void exitActivity(){
    this.finish();
}
```

You want to do this, because if you do it your way you will make multiple instances of your mainactivity when trying to register more items. This can lead to your app running out of memory eventually.

Comment: Wait, I will try it now

Answer (score 1):

Does it throw an Error or is it just doing nothing ?

Also you could try:

```
Intent registerIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(registerIntent);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Code shows error, the (this, MainActivity.class) has error

Answer (score 1):

Try this 1 line code in your 'onClick' method:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
```